# AWS Lambda, NodeJS, pg-promise library - High latency > 10000ms

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, pg-promise

I have an AWS Lambda function setup using NodeJS, which makes a call to a postgres database using the pg-promise library to retrieve data - which then sends HTTPS GET requests etc. but none of the rest is important.

I was using the 'pg' library originally but ran into connection closing & async issues which is why I switched to pg-promise (Which DID fix my other problem!). With the regular pg library I was getting expected latency of <1000ms

I have boiled down and redacted the code to just a simple query, and I am getting these response times from the last 3 test runs: 11790.78 ms, 11232.22 ms, 12002.04 ms. Every single time it is **over** 10000ms...

**EDIT**: Fixed code

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')();
const https = require('https');
const xmlParser = require('xml2js').Parser();

const client = pgp({
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.PORT,
    user: process.env.USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD
});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {  
    client.one("SELECT period FROM pay WHERE company='XXX' ORDER BY moddate DESC LIMIT 1;")
        .then(function(data) {
            callback(null, {
                "statusCode": 200,
                "headers": {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                "body": data.period
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
};
```

As stated, I was having no problems with latency when using the 'pg' library, so I know there is no problem with the lambda-RDS postgres connection.

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Thanks,

Comment: I wonder if you could try calling [connect](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#connect) directly...it would be interesting to know whether it's opening the connection or the actual query that's taking so much time. Also shouldn't your `callback` either be inside your `.then`...or maybe switch to `await`ing the promise? Right now you're going to be executing `callback` before your promise has a chance to resolve...not sure what effect that has in a Lambda.

Comment: See [async example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) for how to write this code using promises. Or rewrite it so that the handler is not async and the callback executes within the `then` and `catch` handlers. At present, the code isn't correct for either scenario (async or callback).

Comment: @David784 thank you. I have updated the code example provided to reflect proper handling of the callback. The issue still persists however. I am going to do the connection test recommended by you and see what the results are

Comment: @jarmod thank you I have updated the code, the problem still persists however

Answer (score 2):

In the end I figured out what the problem was... leaving pg-promise to automatically shut down the connection pool is what was causing the latency.

Chaining a

```
.finally(pgp.end);
```

after the .catch gave me a 200ms response time.

Thanks everyone

Comment: This is not just closing the connection. This closes all connections in the pool, and then shuts down the pool, so it no longer can be used. It cannot be a good solution for your problem, more like a nasty hack. Any queries running in parallel will die as well.

Comment: @vitaly-t what would be the correct approach for this issue then? I am running into the problem now as I re-implement the rest of the logic. 

After retrieving that data, it runs another query to get UserID's which it loops thru - sending a GET request and then writing those responses back to the database. As you can imagine I am now hitting connection closed issues when trying to write back to the database the final time (inside of the loop)... Thank you sir

Comment: Lambda is known to be the most problematic system when it comes to connections. It applies the most aggressive connection-closing policy. This creates a number of problems. [There has been a lot of Lambda-related issues logged therefore](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/search?o=desc&q=lambda&s=created&type=issues). I would suggest looking at those. I cannot be more specific, and I do not use Lambda myself.

Comment: @vitaly-t thank you... I was eventually able to solve this by handling half the request and lambda and the final database writeback by the application itself... I **am** using .finally(pgp.end) as a chain after the final .then resolves, so I don't think this would be considered "hacky" ?